# Reg import does not work in batch script

Tags: windows, search, batch-file, replace, registry

I'm trying to figure out why my reg import command is not working in the script below.
When I run the reg import fileName.reg from the DOS it works fine but when included in the script below it does nothing and I cannot find why.  I can see the export completed correctly and the format looks ok to me. When I use the the reg import command on the same exported file it works fine.  Below is the code.

Thx......

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM  This script updates the Windows Registry for the 

REM update Admin Nodes
set service1Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MyService1\Parameters
set service2Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MyService2\Parameters

echo updating [%service1Key%]
call :updateRegKeys %service1Key%
echo updating [%service2Key%]
call :updateRegKeys %service2Key%

SET count=3
set looper=1

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%count%) DO (call :updateAllServers %%A)
GOTO:EOF

:updateAllServers
SET domainKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MyDomain%looper%\Parameters
SET otherDomainKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MyOtherDomain%looper%\Parameters
echo [%domainKey%]
echo [%otherDomainKey%]
echo .
call :updateRegKeys %domainKey%
call :updateRegKeys %otherDomainKey%
set /a looper+=1
goto:eof

:updateRegKeys
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "registrykey=%1"
set findv="-Xms512m"
set replacev="-Xms512m something that is long"
echo "Updating registry values, please wait..."
REG EXPORT "%registrykey%" origReg.txt
call :findReplace %findv% %replacev% origReg.txt > newkeys.reg
reg import newkeys.reg
del /q newkeys.reg origReg.txt

:findReplace
REM finds and replaces a string 
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
set "line=%%B"
if defined line (
    call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
) ELSE echo.
)
```

goto:eof

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'escape' all backslashes in your *.reg script, e.g. (notice the '\\'):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"LIB_DIR"="C:\\Libraries"
```

Otherwise it will not work and you will have absolutely no idea why (no errors, warnings just nothing happens). I had this problem some time ago.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm able to run the reg import on the same exported file manually so I'm pretty sure that's not the case.